# Ruby on Rails Base URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I am using Phusion Passenger to host a rails app on an Apache server (I am very new to rails).

I have several domain names that point to the same server, and a `mod_rewrite` is used to direct different domains to different subdirectories.

I was having a difficult time getting the app to load at all, but I set `RailsBaseURI` to the path relative to the `DocumentRoot`, and everything worked fine. However, all the links generated throughout the application include this `BaseURI` in them.

How can I configure the app to generate URI's relative to the naked domain name instead?

Comment: You probably want to use mod_proxy rather than mod_rewrite.

Comment: Could you perhaps expand upon this, or link me to some resources on the matter?

Comment: To clarify... do you want app1.mydomain.com to serve the rails app located at /var/www/app1, app2.mydomain.com to serve the rails app located at /var/www/app2, etc?  Or, are you trying to redirect app1.mydomain.com and app2.mydomain.com to mydomain.com/app1 and mydomain.com/app2?  The former is a job for virtual hosts and the latter is easily accomplished by following the passenger docs: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri .  If you can clarify exactly your goal, I am happy to be more specific.